# Action routing in .Net Core 3 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am busy migrating an existing-working WebApi from .Net Core 2.2 to 3, however, the routing stopped working. I keep getting a 404 Not Found message.

Would like to use the action names as part of the route template in my controller, for example:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

> Call example: /api/Lookup/GetBranchesAsync

I'm just really confused about why it stopped working.

Please see the code below.

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
    services.AddScoped<ILookupService, LookupService>();
    services.AddScoped<IFranchiseRepo, FranchiseRepo>();            
    services.AddScoped<ILogRepo, LogRepo>();

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);           
  }

  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]    
[Produces("application/json")]    
public class LookupController : Controller
{
   private readonly ILookupService lookupService;

   public LookupController(ILookupService lookupService)
   {
       this.lookupService = lookupService;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetBranchesAsync()
   {

   }

   [HttpGet("{branchID}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetBranchSEAsync(int? branchID)
   {

   }
}
```

Any advice on what the issue could be?

Comment: It is probably the encryption mode that TLS is using.  You may be going from 32 bit encryption to 64 bit encryption mode.  To make a HTTPS (secure connection) and TLS  connection must be established.  I've seen a lot of issues with upgrading.  the encryption mode must match the certificate and if you have a 32 bit certificate you cannot use a 64 bit encryption mode.  The Net library I think has errors and going from Core 2.2 to 3.0 is probably going from 32 bit to 64 bit.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Remove the leading `/` in the route template

Comment: @jdweng I am currently testing local and not using any certificates or https connections.

Comment: Are you sure your server is using https.  May be check with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  I would compare the headers in 1st request in the original core with with upgrade machine.  The failure has to do with the defaults headers.  You may be correct that you are not using HTTPS, but a default header is being set different on core 3.0 in the Net Library.  Then you would have to add a missing header into the code to make new header look like old header.  Also check http version (1.0 : stream, 1.1 chunk) with sniffer.  Also check if IP is V4 or V6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8998, in .NET Core 3.0 `Async` is skipped by default in Action name. Your endpoint is available at `/api/Lookup/GetBranches`. You can change this behaviour by replacing

```
services.AddControllers();
```

with

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
```

in `ConfigureServices` method, or just use the new routes

Comment: I did this  services.AddControllersWithViews(x=>x.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);